# does clamav work on windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clamav

I scanned my pendrive using clamscan which has a virus but it is showing 0 infected file.

Comment: It may but that's a bad idea anyway. There are native Windows software for that and is already included in recent Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

It does if the files you scan are windows files and your virus database is up to date and has the virus you know it has in its database.

ClamAV is also intended for scanning attachments in mails and therefor has a limit on the size of files it scans (by default 20Mb and if you provide the option  `--max-filesize=n --max-scansize=n` it will do larger files but there is a hard limit of 4G.

It will however not work on Linux files as the signatures it looks for are based on Windows and our system is fundamentally different. What is considered a virus signature in Windows is likely common coding practice in Linux resulting in 100% false positives.

If you have windows and a windows formatted pendrive scanning from windows would be the more logical way to go. It might even be more prudent to use a live session virus scanner as that would prevent your disks from running and actively fight your attempts to fix things.